# Set min-height equal to content height

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to set a `div` to have `height: 100vh` with a `max-height: 800px`. However, on smaller screens I don't want the `div` to be allowed to shrink below the height of its content. Is there anyway to accomplish this without JS?

```css
.hero {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 800px;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can help you here. You simply need an extra wrapper:

```css
.extra {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.hero {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-basis: 100vh;
  max-height: 800px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="extra">
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems to work:

```css
.hero {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px;
  min-height: 100vh; /* mobile-first (small screens) */
}

@media (min-height: 800px) { /* only for screens of height 800 or greater */
  .hero {
    min-height: 0; /* eliminate the earlier rule */
    height: 800px; 
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, nostrum nulla illum, laborum accusamus veniam sed maxime ratione aliquid facilis rerum maiores ea unde dolore et. Officiis cupiditate veniam odit?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, if you add `height: 100vh` to the media query rule, it produces the desired result. The criteria is the hero should be the height of the viewport, but no smaller than its content and no taller than 800px

Comment: Alternatively, removing `max-height` and adding `height: 800px` to the media query rule also works, and may be clearer and more direct.

Comment: I updated it accordingly. Feel free to change it again or post your own final solution.